# How to configure and Enable WiFi Hotspot through terminal without root

Tags: wifi-hotspot, terminal, wifi-tethering

How can I configure and enable/disable the WiFi Hotspot using the terminal without `root`? Also I want to kick a user from my hotspot using the terminal.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Why do you want to do this using the terminal? Also, are you using an on-device terminal emulator, or a remote shell using `adb` and a USB cable?

Comment: @unforgettableid on device terminal

Comment: Why don't you want to just create a hotspot in the normal way, using the Android GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Setting and enabling hotspot (software access point) is possible by calling methods [`setWifiApConfiguration`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#146) and [`startSoftAp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#130) of `wifi` service. But at least since Android 8, the [former](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/5c5e8b347d32f7bf5bb1e6f40b1e350f1e9fb0f3) requires permission [`OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1286) while the [latter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/edabcd4004fe1ad46e58ee973906913cc3edc79e) requires [`NETWORK_STACK`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1315). Both permissions have [Protection Level](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526) `signature`, not to be used by third party apps. Neither `adb shell` has any of the both permissions. So it's not possible without root access.

A workaround is to simulate `tap`s and `keyevent`s using `adb shell input` command, though it's not a commandline solution in true sense.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to create a WiFi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526)

Comment: How do you set ap band through these commands