# How to turn on the wi-fi hotspot using command line with root?

Tags: root-access, wifi-tethering

I've read a lot posts about it like [How to turn on the wi-fi hotspot using ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173709/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-hotspot-using-adb) but all of them based on "click emulations", but I have root and it doesn't solve my problem.

I've tried [VPN Hotspot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.mygod.vpnhotspot) app and it work perfectly even without root permissions (using only "WRITE_SETTINGS" perm.)

I need to enable it using command line even when phone is locked, something like:

```
adb shell su -c service call connectivity 24 i32 0 i32 0 i32 0 s16 random
```

but for Wi-Fi tethering.

I've Android 11 rooted device.

### Update

I found that it is possible to do this through a similar command:

```
service call tethering 4 null s16 random
```

```
void startTethering(in TetheringRequestParcel request, String callerPkg, String callingAttributionTag, IIntResultListener receiver);
```

But first argument `null` is wrong because here must be this interface:

```
parcelable TetheringRequestParcel {
    int tetheringType;
    LinkAddress localIPv4Address;
    LinkAddress staticClientAddress;
    boolean exemptFromEntitlementCheck;
    boolean showProvisioningUi;
    int connectivityScope;
}
```

How to put it instead of `null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`connectivity` service does not have a method to start Wi-Fi hotspot. `tethering` service indirectly calls `wifi` service which you can call directly.

[`startSoftAp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#147) and [`startTetheredHotspot`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#149) methods start the hotspot, and [`stopSoftAp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#151) stops, as the names suggest.

For Android 11, the order of three methods is `47`, `48` and `49` respectively. So to start:

```
~# service call wifi 47
```

And to stop:

```
~# service call wifi 49
```

No configuration argument is required. Android automatically picks the saved AP configuration.

If a package name is required as argument, try to provide an empty string or `null` or `android` or `com.android.shell`.

Check the method number for your Android version in the service interface file: `android.net.wifi.IWifiManager.aidl` linked above.

All three methods require [`android.permission.NETWORK_STACK`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1673) which has a protection level: `signature`, so won't work without root.

---

**Related:**

- [How to configure and Enable WiFi Hotspot through terminal without ROOT](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219745/218526)
- [How to create a WiFi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526)

Comment: **Thanks! It works!** But I want to know for the feauture, what I should do when I want to call throw `service call` method where some argument is object like in my case `parcelable TetheringRequestParcel`. Is it possible to call some methods like it or only simple like `wifi`?

Comment: @mixalbl4 you can only pass basic data types from shell like integers or strings. See `service -h`. `Parcel` is a Java object, so you need to write Java code.