# How to share a 4G data connection over wired Ethernet?

Tags: tethering, dhcp

I understand that Android is principally an wired-Ethernet client.  i.e. it requests and receives a DHCP address.  The internet is on the other side of the Ethernet cable.

Does any version of Android have the capability of running its wired-Ethernet in an "access-point", "tethering" or "server" mode, where Android's Ethernet provides a DHCP server and NATs Ethernet traffic out through its 4G radio, to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the feature has never been part of stock Android (not sure if some custom ROM provides this), it's possible on rooted devices.

I recently answered to [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526) which may help you make Ethernet work on your device. Once done, there are two more things required:

- Run a DHCP server (we already have `dnsmasq` on device up to Android 9, or you may get a static binary)
- Share internet (by doing IP forwarding and NATing)

Both of these steps are explained in my answer to [How to create a WiFi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526) and the answers linked there. Just ignore the steps related to WiFi and pick the relevant parts.