# Random/change MAC address for WiFi hotspot on Android 11

Tags: wifi-hotspot, mac-address

On Android 11, MAC address randomizations works fine when connecting the phone as a client to a WiFi network. However, I'm looking for a solution to randomize (or specify) the MAC address when sharing the internet connections to others using a WiFi hotspot.

For testing purposes, I use a OnePlus 5T with LineageOS dumpling (Android 11) which is rooted with Magisk.

I've tried setting the MAC address as I would in a normal Linux environment with `ip link set dev  wlan1 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. This does not work, however. `ip a` shows the custom MAC, but capturing the beacon frames emitted by the hotspot feature, the original MAC is still the source.

Comment: You can create a new Wi-Fi interface for Access Point. Something like `iw dev <OLD_IFACE> interface add <NEW_IFACE> type __ap addr <MAC_ADDR>`. More details: [How to create a wifi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526).

Comment: Unfortunately, this ignores whatever I give it as <MAC_ADDR>. And when I change it manually with ip link set ... iw dev and ip a show the custom address, but hostapd won't start (no error, but exitcode 1)